# Windows 10 disappeared (but I can see my files are still there) boot after I installed Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, boot-repair

My Windows 10 is gone after I tried to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. It won't show up anywhere in the `grub` menu but I can still see it in my file manager where it says Windows 10 and all the files are there so I think it is still there.

I ran the repair tool and am at the end now where it says configuring `grub-pc`. I just don't know which of these to mark for my GRUB install devices, should I mark 2 or just one? I know my Windows partition should be in the first one, but when installing Ubuntu, I installed it in the 1TB hard drive. So now, do I select two or just one? Help please!! All my school stuff is in the Windows partition!

The options are

```
[] /dev/sda (256060 MB; SanDisk_SD6SB1M-256G-1006)
[] /dev/sdb (1000204 MB; HGST_HTS721010A9E630)
[] - /dev/sdb5 (166897 MB; /)
[] /dev/sdc (64016 MB; Cruzer_Glide)
```

The Windows partition also still shows on Gparted.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a bootmenu with Easy BCD which is a Windows application and for me it worked perfectly.

First of all , insert Windows Installer DVD and boot it.
 Then select "Repair this computer " option.

After select the command line option located at the bottom of recovery menu. Launch it.

Then type bootrec /fixmbr and execute it. You should now see a message that MBR has been restored or fixed.

Now restart the PC . It will boot directly into Windows. The GRUB must be gone .

Now download and install Easy BCD . After installation, launch it , and select add new entry .

Now select Linux and use GRUB legacy and make sure "automatically locate and launch is enabled " or you can also manually select Linux bootloader drive.

Now save the settings and restart the system.

In the bootmenu , you should now see Neosmart Linux and if you choose it , it will load the GRUB.

Its the easiest method and if you feel uncomfortable with editing GRUB menu you can try it.